# Problems adding Blend behavior to DatePicker

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I'm trying to add a Blend behavior to a DatePicker control to bind an MVVM-Light RelayCommand to the DateChanged event  like so:

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DateChanged">
            <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DateChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DatePicker>
```

I'm using the following definitions:

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
WinRT information: Cannot add instance of type
'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior' to a collection of type 
'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection'.
```

I have successfully used Blend behaviors in this way many other times in my project (and with other controls in the same Xaml file) to bind an event to a command, and the DatePicker control is the only one that has thrown an error. Is there another way to accomplish this or are WinRT DatePickers limited in this way?

Comment: There are a hand full of events that are not supported by the behavior framework. You seem to have found one. `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` is another.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could always invoke the `DateChanged` event handler in the code-behind, and from there I can call the method in the view model. I was just hoping there was a more straightforward way of doing it.