# Cannot add instance of type '%0' to a collection of type '%1' error in windows phone 8.1 DatePicker

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1

Hey I am developing an app in windows phone 8.1 using the MVVM pattern. I want to get the date from the **DatePicker** on the **DateChanged event** in the viewModel.
After running the program I am getting this error:

> *A first chance exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in App1.exe WinRT
>   information: Cannot add instance of type '%0' to a collection of type
>   '%1'. [Line: 117 Position: 97] An exception of type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in App1.exe but
>   was not handled in user code WinRT information: Cannot add instance of
>   type '%0' to a collection of type '%1'. [Line: 117 Position: 97]
>   Additional information: The text associated with this error code could
>   not be found.*

My view is:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="26,-0.333,0,0.5"
                Date="{Binding Dates, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DateChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding InitializeExpenseListCommand}"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </DatePicker>
```

And the viewModel:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _dates = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
    }

    private DateTimeOffset _dates;
    public DateTimeOffset Dates
    {
        get { return _dates; }
        set
        {
            _dates = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ICommand InitializeExpenseListCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(InitializeExpenseList()); }
    }

    public Action InitializeExpenseList()
    {
        return () => Debug.WriteLine(_dates);
    }
```

Can anyone help me in solving this error?

Comment: Nope.  Something is way wrong there.  Reinstall visual studio.  Don't worry about trying to find a solution to this issue--there isn't one.

Comment: Why? is this the only solution?

Comment: "The text associated with this error code could not be found" That's bad news.  Serious bad news.

Comment: I think the error is because of `DateChanged` in the EventName. I have changed it to `Tapped` and then its working fine. Can you tell is anything wrong with DateChanged event? Or any event close to this.

Comment: I have a very similar issue binding to a ColorHexagonPicker ColorChanged event. Could it be something to do with the events tied to those kind of changes? @Will can you explain further why that mesage may be bad news? Other bindings are working as Utsav said (I have the same error).

Comment: I went ahead and did a full uninstall and a clean install. Same error. Perhaps there's some logic to binding to these kind of events (perhaps the event args?) that throws this kind of error?

Comment: There is nothing "way wrong" here. Don't go uninstalling Visual Studio. Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309546/problems-adding-blend-behavior-to-datepicker

Answer (score 3):

My answer might be a bit late but this error (still) occurs (in WinRT 8.1 still with placeholders in the message!) if the event you try to add either does not exist or is not supported by the `EventTriggerBehaviour`. Supported events are: `Tapped`, `PointerPressed`, `Loaded`, `DataContextChanged`, `Click`, `Checked`, `Unchecked`, `SelectionChanged`, `TextChanged`, `Toggled`, `NavigationCompleted`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn469361.aspx