# Binding MVVM Command to TimePicker control in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app, template10

I'm using a `TimePicker` control on a XAML page and try to react on changes in the corresponding `ViewModel`. I added the `Xaml.Interactivity` and `Xaml.Interactivity.Core` namespace to my page in order to use the `Behaviors SDK` to trigger the command once the `TimeChanged` event is called.

```
<!-- XAML Namespaces -->
xmlns:interact="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:interactcore="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

<TimePicker x:Name="TestTimePicker" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Time="0">
    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TimeChanged">
            <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TimeChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TestTimePicker, Path=Time}" />
        </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TimePicker>
```

For the code in my `ViewModel` I use `ViewModelBase` and `DelegateCommand` from `Template10`.

```
public DelegateCommand<TimeSpan> StartTimeChangedCommand { get; set; }

public TestViewModel()
{
    ...
    TimeChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<TimeSpan>(TimeChangedAction);
    ...
}

private void TimeChangedAction(TimeSpan obj)
{
    //do something with obj
}
```

Once the Page is Initialized a `InvalidOperationException` with the following message gets thrown.

```
Adding or removing event handlers dynamically is not supported on WinRT events.
```

Comment: can you tell What is the problem now?

Comment: Sorry! Question updated

Comment: Yes, this comes from Template10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108255/discussion-between-archana-and-nor0x).

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474634/cannot-add-instance-of-type-0-to-a-collection-of-type-1-error-in-windows-p. EventTriggerBehavior doesnt support TimeChanged Event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the discussion @Archana. I found a work-around for my problem.
Instead of using `Binding` to connect with a `Command` in the `ViewModel` I am now using compiled binding `x:Bind` to directly connect the event with a handler in the `ViewModel`.

I updated the `TimePicker` control

```
<TimePicker x:Name="TestTimePicker" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Time="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestTime, Mode=TwoWay}" TimeChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestTimeChangedEvent}" />
```

And the code in the `ViewModel`

```
public void TestTimeChangedEvent (object sender, TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TestTime = e.NewTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474634/cannot-add-instance-of-type-0-to-a-collection-of-type-1-error-in-windows-p)

EventTriggerBehavior doesnt support TimeChanged Event. Supported events are

```
    Tapped
    PointerPressed  
    Loaded
    DataContextChanged
    Click
    Checked
    Unchecked
    SelectionChanged
    TextChanged
    Toggled
NavigationCompleted
```

You have to implement custom behaviour to support TimeChanged event

And Here is a link to implement custom behaviour [implement_custom_behaviour](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/behaviors-in-windows-8-1-store-apps/)

Comment: Seems very odd that this is so difficult to implement MVVM.